# UISerchBar bookmark and placeholder alignment issue in ios 8 for Arabic version

Tags: ios, localization, alignment, arabic, uisearchcontroller

The application has language support for English and Arabic. There is an issue in the automatic alignment of bookmark button and placeholder text in ARABIC version for ios 8. It works fine in ios 9. Please find the attachment for the issue.

**Current Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: Is this a custom search bar? Or is this UISearchBar?